# c++ forward declaration for a friend function in imbricated classes

Tags: c++, friend, forward-declaration

I am trying to define a function member of a **class Extraction** FRIEND with a **class Descripteur**, but when I compile I get the following error :

> *Descripteurs.h:24:57: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Extraction’ friend
>
> void Extraction::globalSet(Descripteurs document);
>        Descripteurs.h:19:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class Extraction’
>        class Extraction;*

given by the code :

```
//in Extraction.h
#include "Descripteurs.h"
class Extraction {
public:
    Extraction(Descripteurs document);
    void globalSet(Descripteurs document);
protected:
    int m_value;
}

// in Extraction.cpp    
#include "Extraction.h"
Extraction::Extraction(Descripteurs document){
    this->globalSet(document);
}
void Extraction::globalSet(Descripteurs document){
    this->m_value = document.m_nbMot;   //this is why I need a friend function
    cout << this->m_value << endl;
}

//in Descripteur.h
class Extraction; //forward declaration, is there a problem with this ?
class Descripteurs {
public:
    friend void Extraction::globalSet(Descripteurs document);
protected:
    int m_value;
};
```

I guess the trouble comes from the fact my classes are imbricated, because **Extraction** uses **Descripteurs** and **Descripteurs** has to know **Exctraction** to deal with the friend function. I thought the forward declaration was a solution, as explained in [how comeforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890756/how-come-forward-declaration-is-not-needed-for-friend-class-concept) or [c++ friend namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492062/why-does-a-c-friend-class-need-a-forward-declaration-only-in-other-namespaces) but I could not find documentation that deal with at the same time friend function, imbricated class and separated files.
and if i remove "Class Extraction;" I get as expected the following error :
*‘Extraction’ has not been declared
  friend void Extraction::globalSet(Descripteurs document);*

friend function over accessor (get functions) is a choice : I don't want to make the attributes accessible from anywhere (in situation the function should take several complex attributes, and not just an int).

Can anyone tell me if I need to add some pieces of code or if there is no way to do this without using accessors ?

Any Help will be welcomed

Thanks

Alexis

Comment: I'm afraid I read that as 'inebriated classes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't declare a member function of a forward-declared class as `friend`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310720/declare-a-member-function-of-a-forward-declared-class-as-friend) for possible workarounds.